# Is there a way to loop the function call of these elements in python?

Tags: python, function, loops, class, call

I would like to loop the function call of these elements...is it possible?

```
 class ClassName:
      def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property
      def printclass(self):
        print(self.property)

e1 = ClassName(...)
e1.printclass()
e2 = ClassName(...)
e2.printclass()
e3 = ClassName(...)
e3.printclass()
...
```

this is what I tried to do...it didn't work

```
elements = [e1, e2, e3,...]

for x in elements:
  print(x.printclass())
```

these are only some notes...not a code

Comment: What exactly didn't work? What are the desired and actual outputs of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If I don't misunderstood your question**, then this is one way you can do it-

```
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property
    def printclass(self):
        print(self.property)
    
instances = [ClassName('send_property_here') for i in range(10)]
for e in instances:
    print(e.printclass)
```

1. Fix some **typo's** on your existing code first. e.g missing `:` end of the `def` and missing required param while creating instances from **ClassName** on `__init__`
2. You can create class instances using `List` and `range`.
3. Iterate that instances list and call the `printclass()`